# Does ASP.Net have a Post and Get array like PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, post, get

I am using asp.net. I am wondering if there is an equivalent way to access data in the `Post` and `Get` arrays like you do in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Request.QueryString Collection for GET and Request.Form for POST:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx